.zprofile not used correctly after High Sierra
I am a Unix user and have been using zsh for more than 20 years.
I have been using zsh as my login shell for many years on macOS High Sierra.
I use only ~/.zprofile and for sharing what is relevant to be common,
with /bin/sh and /bin/bash it calls explicitely ~/.profile.
I don't use any other shell initialization file outside of:
~/.zprofile
~/.profile

Recently I made the switch to Big Sur. And I discovered a problem which didn't occur before and which doesn't occur on any Unix I work on:
inside Terminal and xterm my ~/.zprofile is not correctly read.
Since I didn't pass on Catalina ( too many problems ) I cannot verify if the problem started with Catalina or Big Sur.
If I load it explicitely:
. ~/.zprofile

it is read without any error. Most notably I see it at the setting
of PS1 which is the correct one I see on all other systems I am
working on.
I didn't modify either /etc/zprofile or /etc/zshrc.
Here are my very basics shell initialization files:

~/.zprofile
#! /bin/zsh

. ${HOME}/.profile

PS1="### %B%T   %m%b:%32<...<%/ %# "
export PS1
PS2="#   "
export PS2
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
export HISTFILE
HISTSIZE=1024
export HISTSIZE
VISUAL=vi
export VISUAL
tty -s && stty -istrip


~/.profile
#!/bin/sh
CDPATH=.:~/Links
export CDPATH
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/bin
export PATH
MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/opt/X11/share/man:/opt/man
export MANPATH
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG

BC_ENV_ARGS="${HOME}/.bcrc"
export BC_ENV_ARGS


What have you set as your login shell in macOS?

How do you choose tun run Terminal - what is its startup configured as -  See Settings->Profiles and choose the Shell tab

I didn't modify anything from the default inside Terminal > Preferences… > Profiles > Shell most notably, Run command: empty. ↵Moreover, the problem isn't Terminal specific.

We understand that you didn't change your setup, but the OS version changed, and this may have changed /etc/profile, /etc/zprofile etc. So, please, which shell is set as your login shell?

It's /bin/zsh. I updated it inside my OQ.

xterm by default doesn't run a login shell, unless you configured it to do so.

@fd0 Yes but Terminal.app by default runs a login shell so the issue should be xterm only.

@athena what does echo $PATH show? and echo $SHELL

What are the results of the following command in both apps- echo $0

Unrelated comment... you shouldn't export $PS1.

set -o | grep login is one way to see if the current zsh was launched as a login shell.

zsh reads .zprofile only for login shells, but this is the same in MacOS and in Unix, not zsh specific. You can specify in your terminal configuration what kind of shell you want to execute. BTW, if you need setup code which word for every kind of zsh, whether login or non-login, or interactive or non-interactive, this should go into ~/.zshenv . But be aware since this is read by every zsh, this file is also processed by every zsh script you are running. Be careful what you are putting in there. Settings for interactive zsh only, should go into ~/.zshrc.
